# Get response body from 404 in PHP

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, response, battlenet-api

I am interacting with the battle.net API and I need to get the response body when I hit a 404 page. The problem is I get an error.

I know the page has a body as in the documentation there is an example that has the body (screenshot below). I have also put in a screenshot of my php error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Battle.net Docs]

here is my code:

$responseCode = get_http_response_code($api); //Checks page exists

```
if($responseCode == 200) { //Page exists
    $api = "battle.net/apirequest.......";
    $json = file_get_contents($api);
    $schema = json_decode($json, true);

    $completeQuests = $schema['quests'];
} else if ($responseCode == 404) {
     ...Trying to find out why here.....
}
```

Thanks,
James McNee

EDIT: Also when I go directly to the URL I get the JSON response so I really dont know where this error is coming from.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file_get_content would not allow you to get the content on failure conditions. To get the content you would have to use a lower level library; something like say curl.

Comment: I did look into it and you were 100% right, I used CURL to access the page and got the info I needed, thanks for your help!